# Java to XML conversion

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jsf

I am working on web services here i have one GUI which is JSP (JSF) page, It has four field for e.q. a,b,c,d and one submit button when i press submit it will send all four parameter to the server and server will process them and send one response back to the JSP so here i am sending all parameter through **web service** so my question is how do i develop web service here i mean how can i send parameter from java to web service....   is there any code or help...

Thanks!! 
Vinod

Comment: what kind of web service? SOAP? RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

- Create a [webservice](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html)
- Create w[ebservice clients](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/WebServiceClient/WebServiceClient.html)
- Make call of webservice from your service layer of your app.